# build tool (Gradle vs Ant vs Maven) for java EE

Tags: java, maven, ant, gradle

After some search, I jumped to the conclusion that currently, Gradle is the best build tool for java. 
I have never used a build tool and I want to learn one. Is Gradle really worth it?Should I first learn ant or maven and then learn gradle? Many tutorials assume that the reader knows either ant or maven.
Is ant or maven prerequisite in order to learn gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven or Ant knowledge is not a prerequisite to learning Gradle.

The best tutorial, in my opinion, is [the official one at gradle.org.](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorials.html) It doesn't assume any previous knowledge of build systems.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can jump directly into Gradle without learning Ant or Maven.

I've used a number of build tools for Java over the years (Ant, Maven1, Maven 2, Maven 3, Grade and Buildr) and Gradle is certainly a nice one, in active development, with a strong community and lots of plugins. It's worth giving it a try. Another favorite of mine is [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org), if you know some Ruby.